# Using a function component, how can I use a button to change an element already rendered to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used a function component to render "I have a 1964 red Ford Mustang" to the DOM.

An my goal is to use the "changeColor" button to change "red" to "blue".

I expect "I have a 1964 blue Ford Mustang" to be the output when the button is clicked.

My code below is working, except that the button is not changing the color as expected.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

PS: I can do it with class components that use state. My goal is to use function component to solve the problem. Therefore, I would like to stick to function components. I don't know Redux, hook etc. Is that possible?

```js
function Car(props) {
    const changeColor = () =>{
    return  myObject.color = 'blue'
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        I have a {props.year + " " + props.color + " " + props.brand + " " + 
        props.model}
      </p>  
      <button type="button" onClick={props.changeColor}>
        Changecolor
      </button>        
    </div>
  );
}
const myObject = {
  brand: "Ford",
  model: "Mustang",
  color: "red",
  year: 1964
}; 
ReactDOM.render(<Car brand={myObject.brand} model={myObject.model} color={myObject.color} 
  year={myObject.year}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Why don’t you try to read docs? This is a very basic question about react reactivity. Just move your object or color under state (either local or global)

Comment: @SergiiStotskyi I would like to stick with function components. I can do it with class component that use state. But function components don't use state as far as I know.

Comment: You can use state with functions. Just use `useState` hook for this. There is no other alternative in react. Just local state Or redux/MobX/recoil/etc

Comment: Is `myObject` your "state" object? Move it into the functional component in a `useState` hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
function Car(props) {
   
   const [color,setColor] = useState(props.color);

   const changeColor = () =>{
    setColor('blue');
   }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        I have a {props.year + " " + color + " " + props.brand + " " + 
        props.model}
      </p>  
     <button type="button" onClick={changeColor}>
        Changecolor
      </button>  
    </div>
  );
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **changeColor** doesn't trigger a re-render. Implementing a state would have the desired effect, via a state hook:

```js
function Car(props) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(props.color);

  return (
        <div>
      <p>
        I have a {props.year + " " + color + " " + props.brand + " " + 
        props.model}
      </p>  
      <button type="button" onClick={() => {
  setColor('blue')
}}>
        Changecolor
      </button>        
    </div>
  );
}
```